# .htaccess file not redirecting properly in Codeigniter app

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mamp

I have an app that works on my local machine using MAMP, but fails to redirect to a certain page on the live server. I have narrowed this down to the .htaccess file but can't seem to get the exact configuration. It happens when I sign up a user on my Codeigniter-based app and it's supposed to redirect to another page, but doesn't.

This is what I have currently,

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R,L]
# Hide all PHP files so none can be accessed by HTTP
RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ index.php?/$1

# If the file/dir is NOT real go to index
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on   
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Try to used like this